# Code number of days elapsed since last activity

Tags: r, transform, dplyr

I want to code the number of days elapsed since the users last activity for a churn analysis.

I have tried a code I have found in a related topic but it does not work:

```
da = da %>%
  arrange(dayid) %>%
group_by(dayid) %>%
  mutate(dayssincelastactivity = c(NA, diff(dayid))
```

Lets say this is the data. active indicates if the user was active on this day. I want to add the variable dayssincelastactivity, that indicates the number of days elapsed since a user's last active day.

```
da <- data.frame(dayid = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), active = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1), dayssincelastactivity = c(1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1))

da
  dayid active dayssincelastactivity
1     1      1                     1
2     2      1                     1
3     3      0                     2
4     4      0                     3
5     5      0                     4
6     6      1                     1
7     7      1                     1
8     8      1                     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grouping variable using `cumsum` and `seq_along` each group.

```
with(da, ave(dayid, cumsum(active == 1), FUN = seq_along))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 1
```

---

You can also translate this to `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

da %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(active == 1)) %>%
  mutate(new_val = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#  dayid active dayssincelastactivity new_val
#  <dbl>  <dbl>                 <dbl>   <int>
#1     1      1                     1       1
#2     2      1                     1       1
#3     3      0                     2       2
#4     4      0                     3       3
#5     5      0                     4       4
#6     6      1                     1       1
#7     7      1                     1       1
#8     8      1                     1       1
```